# VS Window cannot be pinned

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am using VS 2017 with the standard window configuration "vb.net".

My problem is that I cannot pin my project explorer window (also: team explorer window, etc.) at the right dock.

To be precise: I can pin it using the little pin in the title bar, but when I run the project the windows are unpinned again. The toolbox on the left side is okay and remains expanded.

Step 1: Everything is okay (Solution Explorer, Properties Windows faded in and pinned)
[image]

Step 2: Running the solution (no matter if debug mode or release mode). Closing the application

Step 3: Solution Explorer, Properties Windows faded out and not pinned any more. I have to reopen and pin it every time.
[image]

I already resetted the settings back to Visual Basic.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> but when I run the project

Under the debugger? There is a separate layout for tool windows when debugging (and tends to include a whole load of debugger specific tool windows).

Which does mean if you want your Team Explorer (for example) tool window hidden on the RHS you need to set its position twice.

Comment: No no - that ist not the point. I mean, after ending debugging, the formerly pinned windows have been unpinned again.

Comment: That's not something I've seen. Do you mean Solution Explorer? And could it be that on leaving the debugger the solution explorer has keyboard focus?